# Stream delegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, networking, stream, cfstream

I am trying to send data between an iPhone and a BeagleBone Black Wireless over TLS. However, I am encountering some strange issues. The issue that this question is about is why the delegate method `stream(_:handle:)` is not called. I've read the documentation and the other StackOverflow questions, but my code already takes into account their issues.

Here are my variables:

```
private var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
private var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
private var inputStream: InputStream?
private var outputStream: OutputStream?
```

And here is my code for opening the streams:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (socket.ipAddress as CFString), UInt32(socket.port), &readStream, &writeStream)

outputStream = writeStream?.takeRetainedValue()
inputStream = readStream?.takeRetainedValue()
outputStream?.delegate = self
inputStream?.delegate = self
outputStream?.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .default)
inputStream?.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .default)
outputStream?.open()
inputStream?.open()
```

This is the delegate method exactly as it appears in my code (it is autocompleted by Xcode, so no issue there):

```
private func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    print("Received event code \(eventCode.rawValue)")
}
```

**For some reason though, this method never gets called.** In fact, I tried sending data, by writing to `outputStream`, and the BBBW actually received the message successfully! (Although, if I try to send a message again, I get a `Connection reset by peer` error.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out!

The issue was that I made the delegate method `private`. Once I got rid of that keyword, everything worked out :)